# Questionary between audio titles in flutter just_audio

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, just-audio

I have a playlist in just_audio after some audio title people have to take action. Fill a questionary or do other stuff.
I get an json array

```
[{
   "type":"item",
   "name":"Intro - Mirin Dajo",
   "stream":"http:\/.......demo0::audio\/mpeg",
   "questionary":0,
},
{
   "type":"item",
   "name":"Dein Mentalcoach",
   "stream":"http:\/\/e.......tdemo0::audio\/mpeg",
   "questionary":0,
},
{
   "type":"questionary",
   "name":"Dein Mentalcoach",
   "stream":"http:\/\......ptdemo0::audio\/mpeg",
   "questionary":6525,
   "questionarytitle":"Fragen zu Deinem Wohlbefinden",
},
{
   "type":"item",
   "name":"Achtung Killer!",
   "stream":"http:\/\/cdn......ptdemo0::audio\/mpeg",
   "questionary":0,
   "questionarytitle":"",
}]
```

type questionary with a questionaryId should open a new screen after takin the questionary the next audio should play.

```
sources.add(AudioSource.uri(
          Uri.parse(splitStream(actualStream.stream)[0]), tag: AudioMetadata(
          title: actualStream.name,
          questionnaireId:
          actualStream.questionary.toString(),
        ),));
```

The sources get added to a list of AudioSource.

Well my question is how can i accomplish that Task. Pausing the playlist showing a Questionary and go on with the playlist.
Any ideas? i tried it with metadata if questionnaireId is not 0 aso..
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, not pretty but working.

```
 for (var entry in entries) {
      sources.add(AudioSource.uri(
        Uri.parse(splitStream(entry.stream)[0]),
        tag: AudioMetadata(
          type: entry.type,
          questionnaireId: entry.questionary.toString(),
        ),
      ));
```

I use AudioMetadata to add the type of my Object and if present the Id of the questionnaire.

```
   final metadata =                   player.sequenceState.currentSource.tag as AudioMetadata;
                  if (metadata.type == "questionary") {
                    player.pause();
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              QuestionPage(entries[player.currentIndex]),
                        ));
                  }
```

In a Lifecycle method i check if the AudioStream is of type Questionnaire and (has the AudioMetadata) and then push the questionnaire.